# Magento Store - SQL Error

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, mysql-error-1054

I get this error in my Magento store when I turn on flat catalogs:

```
SELECT COUNT(_table_views.event_id) AS `views`, `e`.*, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`category_ids`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`enable_googlecheckout`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`display_price_group_0`, `e`.`display_price_group_1`, `e`.`display_price_group_2`, `e`.`display_price_group_3`, `e`.`display_price_group_4`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `report_event` AS `_table_views`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = _table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 10
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.category_id='10' WHERE (_table_views.event_type_id = '1') AND (logged_at >= '2010-01-06 17:03:57') AND (logged_at <= '2010-01-13 17:03:57') GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING (views > 0) ORDER BY `views` desc LIMIT 10

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.enable_googlecheckout' in 'field list'
```

Does anyone know how I would go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Describe the table catalog_product_entity using

```
describe catalog_product_entity;
```

and see if enable_googlecheckout is present in the table as a column. If not present you can try taking it out of the query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(_table_views.event_id) AS `views`, `e`.*, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`category_ids`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`display_price_group_0`, `e`.`display_price_group_1`, `e`.`display_price_group_2`, `e`.`display_price_group_3`, `e`.`display_price_group_4`, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `report_event` AS `_table_views`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` ON e.entity_id = _table_views.object_id AND e.entity_type_id = 10
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND cat_index.category_id='10' WHERE (_table_views.event_type_id = '1') AND (logged_at >= '2010-01-06 17:03:57') AND (logged_at <= '2010-01-13 17:03:57') GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` HAVING (views > 0) ORDER BY `views` desc LIMIT 10
```

Comment: it's not present.  if i just added an empty column would this fix it?  How do I add this?

Comment: Yes you can add the column to the table or you can remove the column from the select list in the query.